# Scala pattern match on classes with a typed parameter

Tags: scala, generics, reflection

I'm trying to pattern match on a custom class with a typed parameter:

```scala
class Foo[A]

def isMyFoo[A: ClassTag](v: Any) = v match {
    case mine: Foo[A] => "my foo"
    case other: Foo[_] => "not my foo"
    case _ => "not a foo"
}
```

That will not work; no matter the type of `Foo`, I will always get `"my foo"`.

The only way I was able to make something like this work, is this:

```scala
class Foo[A](implicit t: ClassTag[A]) {
    val tag = t
}

def isMyFoo[A: ClassTag](v: Any) = v match {
    case foo: Foo[_] =>
        if (foo.tag == classTag[A]) "my foo"
        else "not my foo"
    case _ => "not a foo"
}
```

Is there a more elegant way of doing so? Do I have to keep the `ClassTag` inside `Foo`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Do I have to keep the ClassTag inside Foo?

Yes. The type parameter of `Foo` is erased at run-time, so all you know is that you have a `Foo[_]`. The only way around that is to save the type information using a `ClassTag` or `TypeTag`. If you're going to go this route, I would recommend using `TypeTag`, as you will be able to use more refined types. `ClassTag`s still only work modulo type erasure.

For example, using a `ClassTag`, this is wrong:

```
scala> val fooListString = new Foo[List[String]]
fooListString: Foo[List[String]] = Foo@f202d6d

scala> isMyFoo[List[Int]](fooListString)
res4: String = my foo
```

But the following will work:

```
class Foo[A](implicit t: TypeTag[A]) {
    val tag = t
}

def isMyFoo[A: TypeTag](v: Any) = v match {
    case foo: Foo[_] =>
        if (foo.tag.tpe =:= typeOf[A]) "my foo"
        else "not my foo"
    case _ => "not a foo"
}

scala> val fooListString = new Foo[List[String]]
fooListString: Foo[List[String]] = Foo@6af310c7

scala> isMyFoo[List[Int]](fooListString)
res5: String = not my foo
```